# identical formatting of two underlined lines have different vertical spacing

Tags: vertical-alignment, underline

I'm new to latex but using it to format my CV. I have several sections like the one below, where I expect the two headings "Instruction" and "Lectures and Workshops" to look identical.

```
\section{\sc Teaching}
\underline{Instruction}\vspace{1.5mm}\smallskip \\
Teaching assistant, ... \smallskip \smallskip \\
\underline{Lectures and Workshops}\vspace{1.5mm}\smallskip \\
Using data science ... \smallskip \smallskip \\
```

However, as you can see in this picture, the first underlined line looks much more cramped than the second, which has more spacing between the text and the underline. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Why 2 identical issues ? please remove one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [identical formatting of two underlined lines have different vertical spacing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572179/identical-formatting-of-two-underlined-lines-have-different-vertical-spacing)