# identical formatting of two underlined lines have different vertical spacing

Tags: vertical-alignment, underline

I'm new to latex but using it to format my CV. I have several sections like the one below, where I expect the two headings "Instruction" and "Lectures and Workshops" to look identical.

```
\section{\sc Teaching}
\underline{Instruction}\vspace{1.5mm}\smallskip \\
Teaching assistant, ... \smallskip \smallskip \\
\underline{Lectures and Workshops}\vspace{1.5mm}\smallskip \\
Using data science ... \smallskip \smallskip \\
```

However, as you can see in this picture, the first underlined line looks much more cramped than the second, which has more spacing between the text and the underline. Does anyone know what might be causing this and how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: This a  problem of descender in the second heading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look carefully, you notice that the spacing between the bottom of the letters and the line is the same in both cases. But in the second case you have a "p" which causes the underline to look lower. If you want to avoid this, just add `\strut` which makes the height of each line maximal: `\underline{\strut Introduction}` and `\underline{\strut Lectures and Workshops}`